# How do we force Email Studio to use the supplied email address in the data extension even with an existing Subscriber Key in the All Subscribers List?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-studio, subscriber-key

My question comes from the fact that when sending an email with a Data Extension as the source, Email Studio pulls up the **related existing Subscriber Key** in the All Subscribers list to get the email address that's actually going to be used (as expected).

However, since our SubKey identifies the **customer**, he/she can have multiple email addresses pointing to, say, specific products—which in turn have their own attributes—owned by that customer.

If we were to do product-specific sendouts by making a Filtered DE for example from the mother DE, how do we force Email Studio to **use the different emails** (and by extension, the different attributes)? Could this be done without creating a separate SubKey for each product and/or creating an AdHoc SubKey for that sendout?

So it's not so much that I'm looking for changes in a customer's email address, capturing them, and updating the All Subscribers list, but rather having multiple valid unique email addresses for a single, customer-level SubKey.

Here are some links that might be related:

1. [Override email address in marketing cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201624/override-email-address-in-marketing-cloud) (has no answer, but OP's comment-reply mentioned something of note: "***To all: There is another solution more straightforward: theres a business rule that just needs to be activated to achieve this behavior.***")
2. [Is the email in All Subscribers preferred to the one in the sendable Data Extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280516/is-the-email-in-all-subscribers-preferred-to-the-one-in-the-sendable-data-extension) (talks more about a subscriber changing his/her email address)

Any insight is very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below will help you understand the email address behaviour in Marketing Cloud.

It's a screenshot from Eliot Harper's video which I highly recommend you watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puQ-cOQQu9U&feature=emb_logo

[image]
Source: https://mc.chat/subscriber-email-address-update-behavior/

As you can see from above, it's not possible to achieve this directly in Email Studio.

If you have access to Journey Builder, you could start sending emails from JB using a Data Extension as the Entry Event. This would enable you to send emails directly to the email address included in the Data Extension.

The **business rule** mentioned in one of the links you provided can be turned off by Salesforce support. Turning off this rule, however, can lead to tracking problems down the road along with a few other downstream issues.

Source: https://powerofus.force.com/s/article/SFDO-BP-Multiple-Email-Addresses-Marketing-Cloud

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am rather sure this is one of the drivers behind Journey Builder being pushed hard by SF, to get rid of legacy debt like this.

Comment: You can read more about the different behaviour, in the context of the said Business Rule, in my reply here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261592/subscriber-key-related-to-multiple-emails/261602#261602

Comment: I will be honest, whenever I dig into this 'tracking problems down the road' issue on the business rule, I basically get just the response of 'aliens' and no real answers. Even if I ask about, without the Rule and using their solution of an automation to update the email before the send...wouldn't that present pretty much the same issue if the email is constantly changed? I get no response. I feel like if you have ANY email addresses that change, you would need your own reporting anyway...so what is the real risk of this BR?

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful response! On that unfortunate note, would you recommend JB for single adhoc sends moving forward, and (this might be a bit off-topic) would we be able to use the associated attributes for the different emails?

@LukasLunow, very insightful link as well, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'd go ahead with Single Send Journeys. Re. attributes - that all depends on your data model, not really possible to answer without seeing the setup.

Comment: @Gortonington I think the main concern is SFMC is unable to identify which email address was sent to

Comment: But wouldn't that be true as well after the email was overwritten multiple times in an automation? I agree with the idea to discourage this behavior in general for bulk sends, but I see no real difference between the BR and the Automation solution as far as downsides.  @DavidAngeloBrillantes - I would be concerned on trusting single send journies. The through-put on them is still very low. Any significant volume/frequency could easily choke it.

Comment: @Gortonington - I have updated my answer here, with more details on tracking challenges related to the BR: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261592/subscriber-key-related-to-multiple-emails/261602#261602